# What does %||% mean?

Tags: r, syntax

I have seen the use of `%||%` [within the Seurat package](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/master/R/differential_expression.R) (e.g. line 1662) and was wondering what is the meaning of this expression

Answer (score 3):

You can define custom operators in R. Their names can be pretty much arbitrary, but they need to be delimited by `%…%`.

`%||%` is such an operator. It isn’t predefined in core R, but you can define it yourself, and Seurat did that, [in `R/utilities.R`](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/9b3892961c9e1bf418af3bbb1bc79950adb481d7/R/utilities.R#L1583-L1589).

Its definition is however quite a common one, and can be found in many packages, not just Seurat. Its semantics are effectively this:

```
`%||%` = function (lhs, rhs) {
    if (is.null(lhs) rhs else lhs
}
```

That is: use the first operand, unless that is `NULL`. In that case, use the second operand.

Comment: it is in the `utils` package (if that counts as core) ... but not exported

Comment: @user20650 Ah interesting! In fact, it’s actually a recent addition (2019), and the source code makes explicit reference to copying it from ‘ggplot2’.